# Compile time default values for static members of static struct defined inside classes

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I would like to have a design suggestion from you.

I have a set of classes in C++, every class has a bunch of variables (`double` and `int`) which determines the behavior of the algorithms they implement.

Something like this:

```
class Foo
{
  private:
  double value1, value2, etc...;
  public: 
  void setOptions(double val1, double val2);
  /*
  and here other methods...
  */
};

class Bar
{
  private:
  double value1, value2, etc...;
  public: 
  void setOptions(double val1, double val2);
  /*
  and here other methods...
  */
};
```

I would like to group all these option variables in a single class, so that is possible to dynamically change the variables of the options in the instances of the classes, but I would also like to give the `value` variables a default value as initialization.

I would like that the options variables are different and set with a default value at compile time for every class.

I adopted the following approach:

```
// Options.h
class Options
{
    public:
    Options();

    static struct FooOptions
    {
      static double option1;
      static double option2;
    } fooOptions;

    static struct BarOptions
    {
      static double option1;
      static double option2;
        // etcetera
    } barOptions;  
};
```

and then in the `Foo` and `Bar` classes I use the value `Options::FooOptions::option1` and so on.

The problem here is that I can't initialize those value statically.
I'm used to initialize static member outside in the .cpp file, but in my .cpp

```
// Options.cpp
Options::FooOptions::option1 = 1.0;
```

I get the following compiler 
`error: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘=’ token`

On other hand if I initialize them inside the constructor:

```
// Options.cpp
Options::Options()
{
    FooOptions::option1=1.0;
}
```

I get `undefined reference` error when I try to access it from my `main`.

I think the problem here is that I have two nested static structures. What can be here an optimal solution for this kind of design?

How would you implement a class that acts only as container of `double` and `int` values to use inside classes as parameters of algorithms?

Comment: You forgot the type in the definition: `double Options::FooOptions::option1 = 1.0;`

Comment: Doh!

I've lost one hour!!!
Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you need the options of all classes combined in one `Options` class? Shouldn't every class have its own set of options?

Comment: I want to embed and manage all the class options with a static class which can be simply modified during the program via some sliders (this regards the Qt part of the project).
Doing this way helps to me keep all the important variables in one class without loosing or forgetting things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> // Options.cpp
> Options::FooOptions::option1 = 1.0;
> ```

Add the missing "double" :-)

```
double Options::FooOptions::option1 = 1.0;
```

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
// Options.h
class Options
{
    public:
    static struct FooOptions
    {
      FooOptions() : option1(0.0), option2(0.1) {};
      double option1;
      double option2;
    } fooOptions;
};
```

You don't need struct instances in the class, since all their fields are static.

Comment: I don't want them to be const, since those parameters have to be dinamically modified during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you **over-design** the class. A simple way is to include those option data as private member in your class and provide public setters/getters.

By adding a parameter in constructor, you can customize the default behavior.
By adding setters and getters, you can update the behavior dynamically, i.e., in the run time.

```
class Options
{
  public:
    /* choice=1: fooOptions
     * choice=2: barOptions
     * ..
     */
    Options(int choice);
    void SetOptions(..);
    void GetOptions(..);

  private:
    double option1;
    double option2;
};
```

Comment: Your comments are right, but I want my variables to have a  compile time default value and be able to modify them dynamically.  Probably the way I designed that class do the job...I was forgetting the "double". BTW thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Yup, no problem. Just remember to always use the simplest design. It'll make your life much easier;)